# Calling Java Methods from JNI results in program crash

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Calling get or set methods crashes. Object array is valid. It prints till line 2.Intially was getting error while inserting into the jobjectArray .Also tried with getting the value from Jobject .Both getter and setters fail .

**JNICode is as below :**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_pax_1store_1get_1data_1avail_1info
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jclass1, jobjectArray jobj)

{

.....
.....

     int len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jobj);

    printf ("Incoming object array length = %d\n", len);// - - - > Works.. shows 2 (I am passing 2 objects)

    jobject j = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jobj,0);
        printf("This line 1 \n ");
       jmethodID meth1=(*env)->GetMethodID(env,jclass1,"getTimestamp","()Ljava/lang/String;");
printf("This line 2 \n ");    // - - - - > Works.. 

        jstring string_from_obj = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,j,meth1);   // - - - - > Crashes..
printf("This line 3 \n ");    // - - -> does not print this..
        printf("Contents are =%s\n",(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, string_from_obj, 0)); 

............

}
```

My Java Object is as Below :

```
public class DataAvailable {
String timestamp;
public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
}
```

Call to JNI is as below :

```
public native int pax_store_get_data_avail_info(DataAvailable[] stats_array);
```

Comment: Have you considered adding error checking to your code? You must check *every* JNI method for an invalid return value and take the appropriate action, not just assume they succeeded. In this case, what was the value of the method ID?

Comment: On the face of it, `jclass1` is not **DataAvailable**, but **demo.JNIWrapper**.

Comment: Emphasizing what @EJP asked, what's the value of `jobject j`?  It's quite possible for an object array to have `null` elements, and emitting a simple `printf("This is line 2 \n");` tells you nothing about the success or failure of any previous code - it just lets you know the previous code **didn't crash**, not that it worked properly.  Also, `printf()` to `stdout` is problematic in that it's *buffered*.  Not seeing output doesn't necessarily mean that line wasn't reached - it just means it wasn't output.  If the process crashes before the buffer is flushed, you won't see the output.

Comment: @EJP:how would I get the method ID ,should I just print jobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glaring issue is that pax_store_get_data_avail_info() is not a method of DataAvailable.  It is a method of some other class?  You don't actually say what it is.  But let's suppose it is:

```
class X {
   public native int pax_store_get_data_avail_info(DataAvailable[] stats_array);
}
```

When you call this method, the `jclass jclass1` argument you get is for "X", not for DataAvailable.  So your call to GetMethodID() probably fails.  You don't check the return, so you re probably handing a bad method ID to the next call.  JNI fails are hard crashes and very ugly.

You need to query the jclass for DataAvailable and use that.

Comment: How can I get the array of objects in my C code.Is it possible to get the object type from jobjarray.

Comment: Yes, you can call `(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jobjarray, idx))`